# R: check if value in one of the columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two columns: `x` and `y` . Each column can store 'A', 'B' or NA.

```
 df = data.frame(
   x = c('A', NA, 'B', 'A', NA),
   y = c('B', NA, 'B', 'A', 'A')
 )
```

How to create a `is_a` column which tells if `x` or `y` equals 'A' ?

From the previous example the result would be :

```
df$is_a = c(T, F, F, T, T)
```

Comment: That won't work as it will get NA as having 'A', You can use `ifelse` assignment. Take a look at that.

Comment: How can I make ifelse managing the NA?

Answer (score 1):

We need to use `!is.na(x)` and `!is.na(y)` to make the NA values to be returned `FALSE`

```
 with(df, x=="A" & !is.na(x)|y=="A" & !is.na(y))
 #[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Or another option is

```
 with(df, 1:nrow(df) %in% which(x=="A" | y =="A"))
 #[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add a variable to df dataframe and use ifelse statement
    df$is_a <- ifelse((grepl("A",df$x)|grepl("A",df$y)),T,F)
    [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more possibility:

```
df$is_a <- !!rowSums(ifelse(is.na(df), 0, df=="A"))
#> df$is_a
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score -1):

Use dplyr library, the function mutate..

```
yourDataFrame <- yourDataFrame %>% mutate(is_a = (x=='A')||(y=='A'))
```

True if x or y is A and false if both are NA or B.

Comment: Why using `||` instead of `|` ?

Comment: it doesn't work I have true everywhere:

`df %>% mutate(is_a = (x == 'A')||(y == 'A'))
     x    y is_a
1    A    B TRUE
2 <NA> <NA> TRUE
3    B    B TRUE
4    A    A TRUE
5 <NA>    A TRUE`